# Alphanumeric Sort

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, sql-server-2012, natural-sort

I need quick help in sorting data at SQL side. I am using `Sqlserver 2012` (good if answer give with the new feature).

I already search some links as  [Sorting in alphanumeric](http://www.essentialsql.com/use-sql-server-to-sort-alphanumeric-values/) , [Alphanumeric string Sorting in Sqlserver - Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51602/How-to-Sort-Alphanumeric-Data-in-SQL). But does not give the desired result.

Still What I have try :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Section
    (
           Section varchar(50) NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsit no.43')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsit no.41')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 11')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 1')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 12')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 2')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 3')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 4')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 40')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite No. 41')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite no.20')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Campsite no.41')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Cabin')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Group Tent Campsite')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('Tent Campsite')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('test1')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('test2')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('test11')
    SELECT Section
    FROM dbo.Section
    --Show normal Sort
    SELECT Section
    FROM dbo.Section
    ORDER BY Section
    --Show AlphaNumberic Sort
    SELECT Section
    FROM dbo.Section
    ORDER BY LEFT(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)), -- alphabetical sort
             CONVERT(varchar(50),SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section))) -- numerical sort
    --cleanup our work
    --DROP Table dbo.Section
```

Now what I want is : **if same string find in alphabet part sort on that first and then numeric (consider space also if possible or you may give the result without space like Campsite no.41 and Campsite No. 41 will give in same order)**

```
Actual Result          Expected Result
Campsit no.41          Campsit no.41
Campsit no.43          Campsit no.43
Campsite No. 1         Campsite No. 1
Campsite No. 11        Campsite No. 2
Campsite No. 12        Campsite No. 3
Campsite No. 2         Campsite No. 4
Campsite No. 21        Campsite No. 11
Campsite No. 3         Campsite No. 12
Campsite No. 4         Campsite No. 21
Campsite No. 40        Campsite No. 40
Campsite No. 41        Campsite No. 41
Campsite no.20         Campsite no.20 --this will good to come here, if possible or if not, then remove space and set approriate
Campsite no.41         Campsite no.41 --this will good to come here, if possible or if not, then remove space and set approriate
Group Tent Campsite    Group Tent Campsite
Tent Campsite          Tent Campsite
test1                  test1
test11                 test2
test2                  test11
```

Comment: Your rules are bonkers. When the string ends `No. xxx` you want to teat the `xxx` as numeric, but the `testxxx` you still want to treat the `xxx` as a string (else the order would go `test1`, `test2`, `test11`).

Comment: sorry for this.. you understand right.

Comment: I understand, its just that I dont think you'll be able to write those rules. Unless you can put into plain English what the rule is for treating the end of the string as a numeric, or not.

Comment: I still don't understand something:  why would Campsite no.20 & 41 come between 12 & 21?

Comment: Do yourself a favour - add a numeric `ordering` column to your section table, maintain it alongside your values and just simply order by that column. sheesh! talk about over-engineering a solution.

Comment: Not to pile on in these comments, but your SELECT statement doesn't do what you say it does.  For entries that have no numeric characters, PATINDEX returns a 0, which then does a LEFT(string,0) which returns '', which means regardless of what the first letter is, non-numeric entries will always come first.  (i.e. Tent Campsite will come before Campsite no.41)

Comment: Logic is if same alpha string founds in rows , then first sorting on that, then numeric field sort. If this is simple logic , then I also manage at my-end.

Comment: Thanks all for this.. please upvote. Because I search which work on numeric or alphanumeric string. I have string which may have numeric. And that's why sorting is difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tip: Whenever you are having problems with the sort, add order by items to your select clause. this will enable you to see if what you are sorting by is actually what you want to sort by:

```
SELECT Section,
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) > 1 THEN
          LEFT(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)-1)
        ELSE 
          Section
        END As alphabetical_sort, -- alphabetical sort
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) > 1 THEN
          CAST(SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section)) as float)
        ELSE
          NULL
        END As Numeric_Sort
FROM dbo.Section
ORDER BY alphabetical_sort, Numeric_Sort
```

After I've got the sort correctly, All I had to do is move the case statements to the order by clause:

```
SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) > 1 THEN
        LEFT(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)-1)
    ELSE 
        Section
    END , -- Alphabetical sort
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) > 1 THEN
        CAST(SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section)) as float)
    ELSE
        NULL
    END  -- Numeric sort
```

Basically, You had 4 major problems:

- Your alphabetical sort expression assumed that every row have numbers in it.
- Your alphabetical sort expression contained the numbers as well as the text.
- Your numeric sort expression had both numeric and alphabetical values.
- Because of article 3, you couldn't cast your numeric sort expression to a numeric type, and this is why you would get you a string sort.

[See this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d43b9/13)

Comment: Yes, I am stuck due to the alphabet and alphanumeric string is there.

Comment: Did you check the sql fiddle?

Comment: Why SQL Server don't know how to sort alphanumeric text automatically? Why could not it follows what Windows do? Even MySQL knows how to handle it correctly.

Comment: @ParisQianSen Why do you think so? sorting strings that happen to contain numbers is still a string sort, even in windows. the point is that the strings `"1", "11", "2"` **are** sorted correctly, while the numbers `1, 11, 2` are not.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Common sense bro, we will never put `Volume 10` next to `Volume 1` instead of `Volume 9`. It must be some performance consideration. What if I am willing to trade some performance of machine for the convenience of human. I cannot do that. There is rarely your `"1", "11", "2"` use case can be considered **correct** by human being.

Comment: @ParisQianSen yeah, well, computers are not humans... string sort works the way it does, not the way you want it to. If you want to sort `Volume 9` after `Volume 1` but before `Volume 10`, you need to convert the numeric part of the string to numbers. That's just how it is - I didn't write the sort algorithm for that, I don't know why your complaint is addressed to me.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Really sorry for my words, English is not my mother tongue, my intention is not well expressed. I just want to prove that MSSQL missed one important feature which MySQL have. It may result in tedious SQL scripts, period. Please don't take it personal. Thanks for explaining to us.

Comment: @ParisQianSen Don't worry, I'm not offended or anything. I'm not a fan of MySql (admittedly, I have very little experience with it but it does have some serious drawbacks IMO) so I've never tried it's alphanumeric sort capabilities. Anyhow, good to know they got something better then others.

Answer (score 1):

The below gives the result you are after, but I doubt it is fool proof. I think you are going to struggle to get a solution that is infallible and still performs well.

The first part is to get the first number (where it occurs after a space so that `Campsite no.41` is treated differently to `Campsite no. 40`), I have put this into an APPLY to make it easier to re-use the result.

The next stage is to find the first non-numeric character after the first number, i.e. where the number ends, so that we can extract the full number using substring, then finally use `TRY_CONVERT(INT` to get this extract into a sortable type.

```
SELECT  s.Section, 
        TextPart = SUBSTRING(s.Section, 1, ISNULL(fn.FirstNumber, LEN(s.Section))),
        Number = CASE WHEN FirstNumber IS NULL THEN NULL
                    ELSE TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(s.section, fn.FirstNumber + 1, ISNULL(ln.LastNumber, LEN(s.Section)))) 
                END
FROM    dbo.Section AS s
    -- GET FIRST NUMBER (WHERE PRECEDING CHARACTER IS A SPACE
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('% [0-9]%', s.section), 0)) AS fn (FirstNumber)

    -- GET FIRST NON NUMERIC CHARACTER AFTER FIRST NUMBER
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(s.section, fn.FirstNumber + 1, LEN(s.Section))), 0)) AS ln (LastNumber)
ORDER BY TextPart, Number;
```

*n.b. You would need to move the expressions in the select into the order by rather than the column alias, but I have left it in this format to make it more clear what is going on*

I have tried to comment the solution, but there is a fair bit going on so a full explanation of each bit will be quite hard. Sorry, if anything is not clear

---

**EDIT**

Sorry, missed the update where you switched from wanting (test1, test11, test2) to (test1, test2, test11). This just changes your logic to look for the first letter, but now it is where the previous character is not a fullstup (`PATINDEX('%[^.][0-9]%', s.section)`) rather than where the previous character was a space as before (This ensures that `Campsite no.20` is sorted after `Campsite no. 40`)

```
SELECT  s.Section, 
        TextPart = SUBSTRING(s.Section, 1, ISNULL(fn.FirstNumber, LEN(s.Section))),
        Number = CASE WHEN FirstNumber IS NULL THEN NULL
                    ELSE TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(s.section, fn.FirstNumber + 1, ISNULL(ln.LastNumber, LEN(s.Section)))) 
                END
FROM    #Section AS s
    -- GET FIRST NUMBER (WHERE PRECEDING CHARACTER IS NOT A FULL STOP
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^.][0-9]%', s.section), 0)) AS fn (FirstNumber)

    -- GET FIRST NON NUMERIC CHARACTER AFTER FIRST NUMBER
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(s.section, fn.FirstNumber + 1, LEN(s.Section))), 0)) AS ln (LastNumber)
ORDER BY TextPart, Number;
```

Comment: He may want to specify in a where clause that he only uses this sort when the string ends in a number.  Otherwise I could see things getting pretty whacky.

Comment: Everything fine, but not get the proper order in last 3 entry.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this. Note: Cabin is in your data, but not your expected results. Also if you want something changed with the spaces, just let me know.

```
SELECT  Section,
        FormatSection
FROM dbo.Section
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) != 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(Section,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)) + FORMAT(CAST(SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),5) AS INT),'0#')
                        ELSE Section
                    END
            ) AS CA(FormatSection)
ORDER BY FormatSection
```

Results:

```
Section                                            FormatSection
-------------------------------------------------- ---------------------
Cabin                                              Cabin
Campsit no.41                                      Campsit no.41
Campsit no.43                                      Campsit no.43
Campsite No. 1                                     Campsite No. 01
Campsite No. 2                                     Campsite No. 02
Campsite No. 3                                     Campsite No. 03
Campsite No. 4                                     Campsite No. 04
Campsite No. 11                                    Campsite No. 11
Campsite No. 12                                    Campsite No. 12
Campsite No. 40                                    Campsite No. 40
Campsite No. 41                                    Campsite No. 41
Campsite no.20                                     Campsite no.20
Campsite no.41                                     Campsite no.41
Group Tent Campsite                                Group Tent Campsite
Tent Campsite                                      Tent Campsite
test1                                              test01
test2                                              test02
test11                                             test11
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following alternative.

Create this function and just use this function in your query "ORDER BY fnGetNumericFromString([columnNm])".

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetNumericFromString (@InString VARCHAR(20), @OutStrType VARCHAR(3))
    RETURNS VarChar(20)
    AS
    BEGIN
    -- declare variables
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @strLength INT
    DECLARE @NumericString VarChar(20)
    DECLARE @CharString VarChar(20)
    DECLARE @ReturnValue VarChar(20)
    -- set values
    SET @NumericString = ''
    SET @CharString = ''
    SET @pos= 1
    SET @strLength = LEN(@InString)
    SET @InString = UPPER(@InString)
    SET @OutStrType = UPPER(@OutStrType)

    --start looping
    WHILE @pos <= @strLength 
    BEGIN
    -- number codes are 48 to 57
    IF ASCII(SUBSTRING(@InString, @pos, 1))BETWEEN 48 AND 57
    SET @NumericString = @NumericString + SUBSTRING(@InString, @pos, 1)
    else
    SET @CharString = @CharString + SUBSTRING(@InString, @pos, 1)

    --increment to next character
    SET @pos = @pos + 1
    END

    IF @OutStrType = 'STR'
    SET @ReturnValue = @CharString
    ELSE
    SET @ReturnValue = @NumericString

    RETURN @ReturnValue
    END


select section from Section
order by dbo.fnGetNumericFromString(section, 'str'), CAST(dbo.fnGetNumericFromString(section, 'int') AS INT)
```

Comment: We can rewrite above example using PATINDEX also instead of SUBSTRING.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC (ID)=1 THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,2),SUBSTRING(Id, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Id), LEN(Id)))END DESC)Rn ---- numerical
FROM
(
SELECT '1'Id UNION ALL
SELECT '25.20' Id UNION ALL
SELECT 'A115' Id UNION ALL
SELECT '2541' Id UNION ALL
SELECT '571.50' Id UNION ALL
SELECT '67' Id UNION ALL
SELECT 'B48' Id UNION ALL
SELECT '500' Id UNION ALL
SELECT '147.54' Id UNION ALL
SELECT 'A-100' Id
)A
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC (ID)=0                                /* alphabetical sort */ 
     THEN CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Id)=0
               THEN LEFT(Id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Id))
               ELSE LEFT(Id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Id)-1)
          END
END DESC
```