# SQL sort by number contained as substring

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this

```
Name     SortOrder
-------------------
Lower 1      3
Lower 10      2
Lower 2      1
Lower 1%     6 
Lower 1.5%   5
Lower 3%     4
Average      7 
Upper 1      10
Upper 10      8
Upper 1%     12
Upper 1.5%   11
Average       10  /* sorted 
Average Poor  11  * alphabetically
Rich          12  * only */
Min_Low10     17
Min_Low20     18
Min_Low30     19
Min_Up10      20
Min_Up20      21
Min_Up30      22
```

I want to update the sort orders so that when I sort by it, it will be like this

```
Name     SortOrder
-------------------
Lower 3%     1
Lower 1.5%   2
Lower 1%     3 
Lower 10      4
Lower 2      5
Lower 1      6
Min_Low30     7
Min_Low20     8
Min_Low10     9
Average       10  /* sorted 
Average Poor  11  * alphabetically
Rich          12  * only */
Min_Up10      13
Min_Up20      14
Min_Up30      15
Upper 1      16
Upper 2      17
Upper 10      18
Upper 1%     19
Upper 1.5%   20
```

i.e. those subgroups with a numerics should either be sorted ascending or descending (depending if its lower or upper) and anything else without a numeric should be simply sorted alphabetically and put inbetween.

I think I have group by the first characters of each subgroup then convert the numeric and order by that. But it gives me an error message when I try to convert it: `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

> ```
> SELECT * 
>   ,RowNum =
>   CASE 
>       WHEN Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]' THEN 
>           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SUBSTRING(Name,1,5) ORDER By CAST(SUBSTRING(Name,7,LEN(Name)-3) as decimal) DESC)
>       WHEN Name LIKE 'Lower %' THEN 
>           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SUBSTRING(Name,1,5) ORDER By SUBSTRING(Name,7,LEN(Name)) DESC)
>       WHEN Name LIKE 'Upper %[%]' THEN 
>           (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SUBSTRING(Name,1,5) ORDER By SUBSTRING(Name,7,LEN(Name)-3)))
>       WHEN Name LIKE 'Upper %' THEN 
>           (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SUBSTRING(Name,1,5) ORDER By SUBSTRING(Name,7,LEN(Name))))
>
>       ELSE -1
>   END
>   FROM Table1 
>   ORDER BY RowNum
> ```

here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ada3a/1)

Edit: changed data values as they include 1 as well as 10 which would be sorted wrong if they are varchars.

Comment: Can you select `SUBSTRING(Name,7,LEN(Name)-3)` and see what it gives? I'm guessing it's not a `decimal`..

Comment: No, it is a varchar. thats why i want to cast it to a decimal

Comment: I know that, but what does `SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,7,LEN(Name)-3) FROM Table1 WHERE Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]'` return?

Comment: I'd try `LEN(Name)-1`

Comment: It returns the digits only, so 3, 2.5, 1

Comment: Len(Name)-1 somehow seems to return the % sign

Comment: Could you please provide proper DDL and test data to work with? Either in the question or at http://www.sqlfiddle.com. Seems like you're dealing with trailing spaces or something?

Comment: here is the sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ada3a/1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alphanumeric Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676432/alphanumeric-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select *
    , RowNum =
     ROW_NUMBER() over (order by 
        case 
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]' then 1
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %' then 2
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Low%' then 3
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Up%' then 5
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %[%]' then 7
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %' then 6
            else 4
        end
        , convert(numeric(6,2), case 
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]' then replace(replace(Name, 'Lower ',''),'%', '')
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %' then replace(Name, 'Lower ','')
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Low%' then replace(Name, 'Min_Low','')
        end) desc
        , convert(numeric(6,2), case 
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Up%' then replace(Name, 'Min_Up','')
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %[%]' then replace(replace(Name, 'Upper ',''),'%', '')
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %' then replace(Name, 'Upper ','')
        end)
        , Name
    ) 
from #Table1
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the update statement:

```
update #Table1 set SortOrder = t2.RowNum
from #Table1 t1
  join (
select *
    , RowNum =
     ROW_NUMBER() over (order by 
        case 
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]' then 1
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %' then 2
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Low%' then 3
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Up%' then 5
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %[%]' then 7
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %' then 6
            else 4
        end
        , convert(numeric(6,2), case 
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]' then replace(replace(Name, 'Lower ',''),'%', '')
            when Name LIKE 'Lower %' then replace(Name, 'Lower ','')
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Low%' then replace(Name, 'Min_Low','')
        end) desc
        , convert(numeric(6,2), case 
            when Name LIKE 'Min_Up%' then replace(Name, 'Min_Up','')
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %[%]' then replace(replace(Name, 'Upper ',''),'%', '')
            when Name LIKE 'Upper %' then replace(Name, 'Upper ','')
        end)
        , Name
    ) 
from #Table1) t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for outputting, but how would I update the SortOrder column to be set to RowNum?

Comment: Thanks, the update almost worked. It should be `t1.Name = t2.Name` at the end though.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the base SELECT you could use for update your table or directly to get results

Fixed the issues using:

```
SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER By RowNumber) SortOrder
FROM (
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Name, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER By RowName, Value DESC) RowNumber
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Name,RowName = CASE 
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]%' THEN 'LowerP'
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Lower %' THEN 'LowerS'
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Min_Low%' THEN 'LowerX'
        ELSE 'LowerZ' + Name
    END, Value = CASE 
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Lower %[%]%' THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Name, 6, LEN(Name)-6))
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Lower %' THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Name, 6, 10))
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Min_Low%' THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Name, 8, 10))
        ELSE 100
        END
    FROM Sorting 
    WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%Up%'
    ORDER BY RowName, Value DESC) a
UNION
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Name, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER By RowName, Value ASC) + 1000 RowNumber 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Name,RowName = CASE 
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Min_Up%' THEN 'UpperA'
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Upper %' AND NOT SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name), 1) = '%' THEN 'UpperB'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name), 1) = '%' THEN 'UpperC'
        ELSE 'Middle'
    END, Value = CASE 
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Upper %[%]%' THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Name, 6, LEN(Name)-6))
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Upper %' THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Name, 6, 10))
        WHEN Name LIKE 'Min_Up%' THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Name, 7, 10))
        ELSE 100
        END
FROM Sorting 
WHERE Name LIKE '%Up%'
ORDER BY RowName, Value ASC ) b
ORDER BY RowNumber ) c
```

Comment: This looks fine except the entries in the middle are not sorted alphabetically

Comment: I just realised it doesn't work for my actual data set which has Lower 3 as well as Lower 30%, they would be sorted incorrectly. I updated the original post

Comment: Added a new revision to overcome the issues

Comment: I marked Gabor's answer as correct as it seems slightly easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit compacted version:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM (SELECT Name, SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Name), LEN(Name)
                                   - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Name)
                                   - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Name)) + 2) n FROM @t) t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(ORDER BY CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'lower %[%]' THEN 1
               WHEN Name LIKE 'lower %' THEN 2
               WHEN Name LIKE 'min_low%' THEN 3
               WHEN Name LIKE 'min_up%' THEN 5
               WHEN Name LIKE 'upper %[%]' THEN 7
               WHEN Name LIKE 'upper %' THEN 6
               ELSE 4 END, 
          CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'lower%' OR Name LIKE 'min_low%' 
               THEN CAST(n AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) END DESC, 
          CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'upper%' OR Name LIKE 'min_up%' 
               THEN CAST(n AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) END, 
          Name)
```