# how to sort alphanumeric data in sql..?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have items table which is having Size as follows:

```
1sq.mm.
1.5sq.mm.
0.5sq.mm.
2.5sq.mm.
0.75sq.mm.
4sq.mm.
20mm
25mm
20mtr
75mm x 50mm
100mm x 50mm
100mm x 100mm
75mm x 75mm
```

i  wanted to display it has

```
0.5sq.mm.
0.75sq.mm.
1.5sq.mm.
2.5sq.mm.
4sq.mm.
20mm
20mtr
25mm
75mm x 50mm
75mm x 75mm
100mm x 50mm
100mm x 100mm
```

i tried the following sql query but am getting error

```
'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1 sq.mm.' to data type int.'
```

SQL query:

```
  select * from Items 
  order by CAST(SUBSTRING(Sizes, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Sizes), LEN(Sizes)) AS INT)
```

Comment: Is everything always in sq.mm.? If not how do you define order based on units?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alphanumeric Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676432/alphanumeric-sort)

Comment: @Supreethsup: Since these strings are a part of the size column, I'm guessing they are size units, meaning that `0.5sq.mm` might be different then `0.5pcs`. It's fairly easy to break the data into numeric and varchar values, but calculating the correct order based on the different units might be a little tricky. btw, you should never keep mixed data like this. if possible, separate the size and the units to different columns.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Reiterating what Zohar said, if possible have two columns, size and unit.

Comment: What's bigger 20sq.mm. or 20mm? It's two complete different dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Sizes       
FROM Items
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(Sizes, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', Sizes)-1) as numeric(9, 2))
```

that's assuming your data will always be number followed by at least one alphabetic char.

[sql fiddle (thanks to matt!)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/577e4/8)

Comment: glad to help, tough most of the work was done by Matt... I've already upvoted his answer, you should thank him, not me :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use `REPLACE` in the `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT Sizes
FROM Items
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(Sizes,'sq.mm.','') as NUMERIC(9,2))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sizes
0.5sq.mm.
0.75sq.mm.
1sq.mm.
1.5sq.mm.
2.5sq.mm.
4sq.mm.
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad91f/3/0

Comment: If I am not wrong, leaving sq.m (since it the same in all entries) should not affect the sorting.

Comment: Without the `REPLACE` int he `ORDER BY` it doesn't come out in the correct order

Comment: @apomene: `1sq.mm` and `1.5sq.mm` will be having problem then.`1.5sq.mm` will be before `1sq.mm`.

Comment: you are missing a `CAST` to `numeric` in order by. without the cast its doing a string compare. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad91f/3

Comment: hi @Matt thanks for your solution it works but i have scenario where sizes not just contains 'sq.mm' it also contains 'mtr', 'pcs' in such situations is there any way to replace any alphabets in Size coloumn

Comment: @Supreethsup if you post up sample data of all possible sizes and conversion logic then yes there will be a solution

Comment: @Matt Question Edited that's how i want to sort but not able to do it

Comment: @Supreethsup what about the mtr value, you cant compare a squared value to a non squared value

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('sada322sds232132132');

drop function udf_GetNumeric;



Result
322232132132



CAST(dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Sizes) AS INT)
```

Comment: Please, don't answer a question with code-only. Explain why you did it this way, and where the error was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a **suggestion** - not an answer:

I would reconsider to design the table differently - if possible.
At the moment, you are sorting a column with two different types of information: length (mm) and area (sq.mm) which makes little sense.

Maybe you would rather have a data structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
  length decimal(5,2),
  width decimal(5,2),
  area decimal(10,2),
  unit varchar(10)
)
```

Needless to say that with this design it would be very simple to sort.